# set multiple environment variables in .desktop file

Tags: .desktop

I can add `env` in `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/`

```
Exec=env FOO=bar /usr/bin/my_prog
```

but I need to set 2 environment variables and no approach that I tried works (using `env` twice, appending second assignment after `;`)

How can I set 2 `env` variables in `.desktop` file ?

Comment: The [documentation for env](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/env.html) says that `name=value` can be repeated. Did you try `Exec=env FOO=bar SNA=fu /usr/bin/myprog` ?

Comment: @Mark Plotnick - yes I have tried that. but only the first variable has effect. The second is ignored

Comment: Cannot reproduce this and for me it works with `Exec=env foo=bar bar=foo /home/user/test/test.sh`. Where `test.sh` echos the two variables `foo` and `bar`. You might want to write a wrapper script as an alternative and call that wrapper script in your `.desktop` entry.

Comment: Do your environment variable values contain any blanks or other non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Besides setting up multiple env vars, I have a special case where my environment variable value itself contains an `=` sign. How to escape it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned above, your variant with the addition of several variables should work correctly

`Exec=env FOO=bar /usr/bin/my_prog`

So either there is some kind of external factor, or the question is not fully  correct

Comment: Besides setting up multiple env vars, I have a special case where my environment variable value itself contains an `=` sign. How to escape it?

Comment: `FOO=foo=bar HELLO=hello=world && printf "$FOO $HELLO\n"` working fine in bash, but you can also quote values for safety

Answer (score 1):

This question keeps getting asked and answered because the answers uniformly don't work, including the selected answer above.

Here are working examples from my customized `.desktop` files

```ini
Exec=bash -ic "export PATH=$PATH:/opt ; /opt/qxmledit/qxmledit %u"
```

*In this case, `qxmledit` couldn't find its libraries because the package was installed in `/opt`.  I added `/opt` last, just in case it finally gets packaged by Debian. Setting the `PATH` fixes this.*

```ini
Exec=bash -c "export PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin:$PATH ; /home/user/Downloads/docear-1.2.0.0_stable_build291/docear.sh "
```

*In this case, the shell to start docear was having trouble finding the right Java to run. I added the java bin directory first to prevent seeing my preferred java binaries.*

The desktop format is very finicky when it comes to setting environment vars.  Don't deviate too much from the format. The double quotes go around everything bash is supposed to execute. Also, I am assuming that **bash** is on your current path.

Also, I used the `-i` option to load bash as an interactive shell. You may not want this.

If you haven't found any better answer, please link to this one.